# How to get data from json in lightgallery jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I face with a problem in use `lightgallery` with `jquery` .When I use constant value for `src` and thumb it works great, but in the opposite it doesn't work with `json` . 
I see this kind of error in `firebug`.
**Error**

> -data-src is not provided on slide item

**HTML Code**

```
<a id="dynamic"  href>Open lightGallery</a>

$('#dynamic').on('click', function(e) { 

            var arr=''; 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'post', 
                url: "@Url.Action("ShowMenuGallery", "Ads")", 
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
                data: '{"ID":"' + @Model.ID + '"}', 
                traditional: true, 
                success: function (data) { 

                    arr=data; 
                    console.log(arr); 
                } 

            }); 


            $('#dynamic').lightGallery({ 
                dynamic: true, 
                html:true, 
                dynamicEl:  JSON.stringify(arr) 
            }) 

        });
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult ShowMenuGallery(int id) 
        { 
            ViewBag.guid = Guid.NewGuid(); 
            List<string> menuImage = new List<string>(); 
            ReturnImages(((Guid)ViewBag.guid).ToString(), id, ref menuImage); 



        List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { src =menuImage[0] , thumb = menuImage[0] } }; 
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
        { 
            operations = data 
        }); 
            return Json(json); 

    } 
public class MyClass 
        { 
            public string src { get; set; } 
            public string thumb { get; set; } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try once this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#dynamic").on("click", function(e) { 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "post", 
            url: "@Url.Action("ShowMenuGallery", "Ads")", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {ID: "@Model.ID"}, 
            traditional: true, 
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#dynamic").lightGallery({ 
                    dynamic: true, 
                    html:true, 
                    dynamicEl:  JSON.stringify(data) 
                });
            } 
        }); 
    });
});
```

For more information see https://boxoverflow.com/get-json-jquery-ajax/